# The system cannot find the path specified from ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd, process.start

I've been working on this all morning so I'm here for some help.  Read many SO questions on this and tried all the solutions without resolving my issue.

I started by just using `Process.Start(batchfile.bat);` It works on some computers but not others.  On the computers where the batch file doesn't work, the command prompt opens and says

```
'ogr2ogr.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The command works fine if you open a command prompt and run it but not by double clicking the batch file.  So I started trying to use ProcessStartInfo.

I am selecting a file and reading the file. What I am reading from the file is not important.

```
strFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

At this point strFilePath is = `O:\\03 Supervisors\\04_Production\\test`  O: is a mapped drive.

I create a batch file in that location and write some commands to it.

```
File.CreateText(strFilePath + "\\" + "kml2shp.bat").Dispose();
```

I write to my batch file the command to be executed.

```
ogr2ogr.exe -f "ESRI Shapefile" "O:\03 Supervisors\04_Production\test\Final.shp"  "O:\03 Supervisors\04_Production\test\_Map.kml"  
PAUSE
```

My code to start the process is now

```
try
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

    if (File.Exists(strFilePath + "\\kml2shp.bat") == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File is missing");
    }
    startInfo.FileName = strFilePath + "\\kml2shp.bat";
    startInfo.LoadUserProfile = false;
    startInfo.Domain = "mydomain";
    startInfo.UserName = "myusername";
    startInfo.Password = MakeSecureString("mypassword");
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    Process.Start(startInfo);

}
catch (Win32Exception w32E)
{
    MessageBox.Show(w32E.ToString());
}

private static SecureString MakeSecureString(string text)
{
    SecureString secure = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        secure.AppendChar(c);
    }

    return secure;
}
```

This results in  [image]

If I don't define the domain, user, and password the command prompt says.

```
'ogr2ogr.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

When I do, it can't find the file.

So why does my `File.Exists(strFilePath + "\\kml2shp.bat")` pass, but the process can't find the file?

I have tried

```
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = strFilePath + "\\";
startInfo.FileName = "kml2shp.bat";
```

This results in [image]

Seems to look like it doesn't like the path in the process being `O:\\03 Supervisors\\04_Production\\test`

I assume the space in the path but I have tried 20 different ways to try to enclose it in double quotes with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Is O a subst dir, a network location or a regular drive?

Comment: @OwlSolo O: is a mapped drive.

Comment: Is `ogr2ogr.exe` in your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: @Thomas Levesque Yes. If I open a command prompt and type it in it works fine.  Just not in the batch file. Very odd.

Comment: My best guess as far as that goes is that you haven't rebooted since the directory in question was added to the PATH.  In that scenario, some processes will see the change and some won't, depending on how they are started.

Comment: @Harry Johnston  You nailed it.  I had changed it to use the full path of the exe.  But when I saw your last comment I tested it on my machine without the exe path and it still didn't work. Rebooted my machine and it now works even without the exe path.  I should have thought of that.

Comment: It is still safest to use the full path if you can.  That way it will work even if PATH hasn't been set.  (PATH is a legacy technology and should be avoided where possible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapped drives aren't global, they are specific to the logon session.  By providing credentials, you're asking `Process.Start` to run the program in a separate logon session, so when the process attempts to start, your mapped drive is no longer available.  Hence the "cannot find the path" and "the directory name is invalid" errors.

It doesn't sound as if you *need* the credentials anyway, so just get rid of them and fix the original problem: the batch processor can't find `ogr2ogr.exe`.  The easiest solution is probably to provide the full path to the executable as part of the batch file.  Or if the batch file isn't actually necessary (it isn't clear from the question why you're using one in the first place) you could try running the executable directly using `Process.Start`.